# Merging entity with a unique constraint

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

I have an entity similar to:

```
@Entity
@Table( name="marchi", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="codice") )
public class Marchio implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    private String codice;

    private String nome;
//...
}
```

I create a *Marchio* with *codice* = 123, then I persist it. OK!

Then I retrieve it from the DB via a query, edit the "nome" property with something and call *merge()*. OK!

Then I create another *Marchio* with *codice* = 123. I put something in nome and call *merge()*.

Result is:

> ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '123' for key 'codice'

Good, actually I can use the first way: query, edit property *nome* and merge.

Consider I don't have only "nome". I have 35 different properties, so I don't want to:

```
Marchio m = em.findCodice("123");
m.setP1("1");
m.setP2("2");
...
m.setPN("N");
em.merge(m);
```

How can I do?

Comment: Did you try to create another Marchio with codice = 123 and the same id from the original Marchio?

Comment: No. I want to update the existing Marchio with codice = 123 with other properties.

Comment: There is no need to call `merge` every time you modify fields, JPA saves modifications automatically, unless you modify your object out of a transaction context. Anyway I don't understand your problem, you need to edit some fields and save the object, how else you can do it other then calling set methods?

Comment: Ok you're right. But I have a lot of properties.

Comment: Is there a way to easily copy all props from one entity ti another except for the id?

Comment: What I mean was: in your entity that is not persisted and that has the property values you desire, you should try to set the id before calling merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood well, you already have a detached object with updated values and you don't want to retrieve the corresponding object from the db and update it calling many set methods.
The only way to accomplish this is to remove the old object and then persist the detached new object:

```
em.remove(oldobj);
em.persist(newobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

In spring data, you can simply

```
myRepository.save(entity)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main intention of the merge method is to update a **persistent entity** instance with new field values from a detached entity instance. Firs of all, we need to get a persistent entity instance from a persistence context and update its fields with new values from this detached instance. So the merge method does exactly that:
finds an entity instance by id taken from the passed object (either an existing entity instance from the persistence context is retrieved, or a new instance loaded from the database)
copies fields from the passed object to this instance
returns a newly updated instance.
When you do that: *"Then I create another Marchio with codice = 123"* you create a new Marchio in **transient state** (without id). New Marchio it`s diferent Marchio then in database. For new Marchio in transient state operation MERGE do sql insert. For old Marchio in persistent state operation MERGE do sql update. For Insert you have a unique constraint. Here is the exception from the database.
First of all, get the Marchio from the base ( find() or getReference() ). Then change the fields in it(Persistent Marchio) and then call MERGE. All this should be one unit of work (one transaction).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@Table(name = "marchi", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="codice"), @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="nome")})

I believe with the above you can have:

codice nome
123     A
123     B
123     C
```

Comment: I don't want to!!! I simply want to update one entity basing on property values in another entity (not persisted)